# Hiding menu items for users who are not in a particular group

Tags: permissions, menu-item

Suppose I have a group `Group1` and it has some members in it.

I have alot of menu items in the Top Menu bar.

I want to hide some menu items for those users who are not member of `Group1`

Is this achievable?

Comment: Not enough credit to comment. Are you referring to the global navigation? If so it is security trimmed, so if they do not have access to something it won't show up in the menu. If that is not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: These are the links I have added manually. These are the links to a sub site. They appears to all users.

Comment: It should still security trim, just make sure you are using the relative URLs.  If you use the full URL it will not security trim.

Comment: Did you find any resolution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow below mentioned steps

1. First create a SharePoint group as you have mentioned `Gropu1` and add all your required users part of that group
2. Open Site Settings > Navigation Settings
3. Select the required link from Navigation Editing and Sorting tree view
4. Edit the item by specifying Audience option (specify the newly created group name)

Comment: Did you tried this solution working for you?

Comment: If you find the solution apart from my answer than kindly post your findings here & close the question.

Comment: there is no such a thing as "navigation settings" menu in the site settings as for today